# Callback Listener Between .NET 6 Web API and Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a backend .NET 6 Web API RESTful service solution that exposes a complex class which is consumed by a Blazor Server App.  Whenever the backend Web API's instantiated class changes values, I need to transmit that changed class to the Blazor app. Currently the Blazor app makes all of the calls to the backend service as would be expected.

I have been attempting to get an EventCallback working to overcome this challenge but it does not work.  All of the examples I have found, such as https://blazor-university.com/components/component-events/, include their example within the same Blazor app.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventCallback` is a struct specifically created to be used in Blazor. It's purpose is to determine the type of the delegate of your event handler.

What you really need is a real time Notification System. It is best implemented through SignalR. Start working on it, and let us know of your difficulties.

[Start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server)

[Here's](https://github.com/enetstudio/SignalRServerIdentityAuthentication) a complete working code sample of SignalR used with Blazor Server App with authentication.

A simpler solution, however, is to create a service that implements a Timer object, to query the database at given intervals.

Comment: First, thank you for your help!  I spent most of the day attempting to get the SignalR code to work but I failed miserably.  I then went with your second suggestion and used a Timer and a heartbeat REST call to loosely couple my backend to frontend events (e.g. Web API in one location to Blazor Server Side in another location).  My challenge now is that, while I get the changes, the await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) call is not refreshing the screen from within the Timer event.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why the SignalR app failed to work for you. You simply have to download the app (click on the green code button), then extract the files into a selected folder. Then open the solution in Visual Studio, compile the app... Since the SignalR app employs Microsoft Identity Authentication, you should execute the command `update-database` in the Package Manager Console in order to create the database. Now run the application... If you want to view the chat page, which is now hidden, you should first register and then login.

Comment: After you've logged in, the chat page will be visible. You can now open a new instance of the application by opening a new tab with the same url, or open a different browser, say Edge, enter the program url, and start chatting with yourself. Note: The level of knowledge required to create such a program is not trivial, so don't despair.  As for your attempt to employ the Timer object, I can't mutter a single word without seeing a minimal reproducible code sample. I've to see code and to inspect it.

Comment: I am not using a database - instead I am running a backend set of Web API services on one server that are feeding a number of Blazor Server Apps on the other side.  Now I cannot get the UI to refresh on the Blazor component no matter what I attempt - even stripping out the SignalR code and just running a Timer.  As for the code sample, it runs on itself and not across two different projects and, for example, it does not provide any help for creating HubConnections on both sides.